# Can't Enable Google Login (omniauth) on GitLab CE

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am having an issue enabling Google authentication with my GitLab install. I followed [this guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/integration/google.md) to add enable Google authentication (the interface changed a bit, but I was able to generate the tokens I need with contacts & Google+ api access for my domain). When I go to my GitLab login URL, no providers are showing up. I also enabled Omniauth. Here is the relevant snippet from my Gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
        {
        "name" => "google_oauth2",
        "app_id" => "not-showing",
        "app_secret" => "not-showing",
        "args" => { "access_type" => "offline", "approval_prompt" => '' }
        }
]
```

I am inclined, however, to think it is an issue with Omniauth itself because in my GitLab admin dashboard, it doesn't show the green "on" icon next to it:
[image: Gitlab Admin Dashboard]

I'm running the server on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reconfigure and restart gitlab after making those changes.

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
...
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['google_oauth2']
...
```

Then run:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```